# errors on firefox

Tags: html, firefox

i have 2 errors coming up on firefox. Theses errors are shown below.

1-there is no attribute "property". This refers to the line below:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="blahblahblah"/>
```

This is to do with linking it to social networks i.e facebook etc

2-there is no attribute onerror. This refers to the line below:

```
<img src="281.jpg" width="125" height="125" onerror="onImgErrorSmall(this)"/>
```

This basically displays a default image if the actual image dose not show up.

the question really is, i know these are not valid attributes but how can i get around them, if anyone has any ideas id be grateful.

Comment: Where exactly is Firefox reporting these errors?

Comment: @Spudley: Not quiet sure what u mean by "reporting these errors" but im just looking at the html validation it does on the bottom right hand side.

Comment: It sounds like you've got a plug-in which is reporting the errors rather than FF itself. I've also got dev plugins for FF, but they're not showing me errors with your code. btw - what version of FF are you using? Also, what is your `DOCTYPE` set to -- HTML5 should allow those attributes (even if they're non-standard; it'll just shrug its shoulders and ignore them), whereas XHTML will actively complain about them.

Comment: @Spudley: im using version 3.6.15. Some interesting points...ill look into them and let you know if any solve the problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For the meta tag there is no property attribute
2. For the img tag there is no attribute called onerror

No way to get around them as they are not part of the html markup

Live with them or remove - they will never validate against a web standard

Answer (score 0):

You pasted stuff into a wysiwyg editor directly from Microsoft Office or OpenOffice document.
These properties are proprietary.

You should clean up or remove the markup before pasting. (Most of wysiwyg editors in use today have this function (a.k.a. paste from Word))

Answer (score 0):

1. [This link](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=58384) may be able to help you out.
2. `onerror` is only supported by the "browser" that Microsoft makes.